# How To Separate Mysqli Query result After Coma

Tags: php

I am bit confused at one situation. I have a table called `slam-book` in which I have a column named favorite games. Now User enters their data like

```
"cricket, foot ball, hockey, basket ball"
```

Now I want to separate this result and want to give link to it like,

```
 <a href="/game.php=cricket">Cricket</a>,
 <a href="/game.php=foot-ball">Foot Ball</a>,
 <a href="/game.php=hockey">Hockey</a>,
 <a href="/game.php=basket-ball">Basket Ball</a>
```

So, I can list all users with specific interest, Please help me to get such result. I want that code which can give me results like #2 code.

Comment: where i are going to take `href="/game.php=cricket"` ?

Comment: `<a href="/basket-ball.php=hockey">` Why is basketball so different to the other URLs?

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry that is an mistake

Comment: https://eval.in/578657

Comment: @splash58 Thank YOu SO Much ! It's Worked :) <3

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to 'guess' the structure from your MySQL database in order to help you but I'll try anyways.

If I understood correctly this is an example of a column in your database:
`cricket, foot ball, hockey, basket ball`

If so, then just do a query like below:

`SELECT favorite_games from slam-book WHERE user_id=ID`

then iterate the result set doing something like:

```
foreach ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // get a list of games
  $games = explode(',', $row['favorite_games']);
  // pretty print for each game
  foreach ($games as $game) {
    // replace space with dash
    $clean_game = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($game));
    echo "<a href="/game.php=$clean_game">ucwords($game)</a>
  }
}
```

Comment: Here you should use  `trim()` function before applying `str_repace()` to a string and while replacing special characters in `str_replace()` you should use `'`(single quote).

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep I applied your sensible suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

For doing this your approach should be:

use php `explode()` function to divide games string to array of games, then Loop through the array and first use `trim()` function  to remove any space from both sides of a string and use `str_replace()` function to replace space with `-`, then print in anchor tag.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$str = "cricket, foot ball, hockey, basket ball";
$games = (explode(",",$str));


for($i=0; $i<count($games); $i++){
    $game = trim($games[$i]," ");
    $game = str_replace(' ', '-', $game);
    echo '<a href="/game.php='.$game.'">'.$games[$i].'</a><br>';
}
?>
```